# Locating detailed origin of PHP "each" warning

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, each

I'm stuck on something that shouldn't exist. I have an each() warning that continuously pops up even though I've search in all of the Vendor's files and cannot find it.

This is my returned warning:

```
The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls
```

To clarify, this is not my code, it is one of the Vendors packages used in a project I am working on, the unfortunate part is is that I have updated to the latest version of this code which was updated to specifically remove the each() function. That’s why I’m trying to locate where this error pops up at.

I do not get any additional information to locate where this issue might be located. What sort of configurations or error logging might I find useful?

Comment: Have you seen this post? I'm not positive but it seems to be the same issue. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235163/php-7-2-each-function-is-deprecated

Comment: From the [PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php): "_Warning: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged._" Try changing your PHP version

Comment: I’ve updated my question to clarify, this isn’t my code and I wouldn’t use each() anyways, just trying to locate where it is.

Comment: Are you getting it in web or artisan command? In the latter, invoking with `-vvvv` often shows debug output and stacktraces. Also, set APP_DEBUG to `true` in your `.env`.

Comment: @TobiasK. - through the web, and alright, I’m pretty sure that it’s set to debug but I’m heading in as it is and I’ll check here soon.

Comment: @TobiasK. - Yes, my .env currently has APP_DEBUG = true and APP_LOG_LEVEL = debug

Comment: Is this just a notice printed on the page, or does your site actually escalate this as an exception and show the error page?

Comment: At the moment, it is just printed. Which isn't particularly helpful in my case...

Comment: And my php.ini reports all errors as well as `display_errors` is set to `ON`

Answer (score 0):

each() has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Comment: I’ve updated my question to include that this isn’t my code, it used to be part of a package which has since removed the each() function, but somewhere, it remains. That’s why I’m trying to locate it...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an IDE which allows you to search all source files in your project for "each("?

Otherwise, you might be able to use a command line tool to do the same.
[How to grep a string in a directory and all its subdirectories (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622328/how-to-grep-a-string-in-a-directory-and-all-its-subdirectories-files-in-linux)

Comment: I've search through my IDE and I cannot find it, every mention of even just each( pops up with foreach(, which is what it was supposed to be after the update from the package manager.

Comment: Can you search with regex?  Something like ([^r]each\() might eliminate the foreach matches.